# the norm of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In in the demonstration of Lax-Milgramm lemma, they use a linear operator $A:V\to V$, where $V$ is a Hilbert space; My basic problem is how to prove that

$$\|Au\|_V=\sup_{v\in V^*}\frac{(Au,v)_V}{\|v\|_V},\  \forall u\in V$$

Till now I have only one inequality,
$$\sup_{v\in V^*}\frac{(Au,v)_V}{\|v\|_V}\leq \|Au\|_V$$

what about the other inequality ? thank you for your time.

Comment: what do you mean by $(Au,v)$? It can't be the inner product, as $v$ is not in $V$. There is a notational failure. You probably mean $v(Au)$. I will edit my answer according to your response

Comment: $(Au,v)_V$ is the inner product, and I meant by $v\in V^*$ that $v\in V-\{0\}$

Comment: Ok. Let me emphasize that this is very nonstandard; of course $\mathbf{C}^\ast=\mathbf{C}-\{0\}$ but here the $^\ast$ refers to the fact that the right hand side is the unit group for the multiplicative structure on $\mathbf{C}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found
$$
\sup_{v\in V^{\ast }}\frac{(Au,v)_{V}}{\parallel v\parallel _{V}}\leqslant
\parallel Au\parallel _{V}
$$
Take
$$
v=Au
$$
Then
$$
\frac{(Au,Au)_{V}}{\parallel Au\parallel _{V}}\leqslant \sup_{v\in V^{\ast }}%
\frac{(Au,v)_{V}}{\parallel v\parallel _{V}}\leqslant \parallel Au\parallel
_{V}
$$
But
$$
\frac{(Au,Au)_{V}}{\parallel Au\parallel _{V}}=\frac{\parallel Au\parallel
_{V}^{2}}{\parallel Au\parallel _{V}}=\parallel Au\parallel _{V}
$$

Comment: thanks a lot, I guess that was the trick !!